# WPF C# System.Deployment Problem

Tags: wpf, deployment, xbap

I'm developing an XBAP application in C# and want to be able to use the System.Deployment object methods.  In the object browser, I'm able to see all the object, when I try and access these methods via the code, it will not work and states that the methods are not in the name space.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your issue but are your XBAP running in "full trust mode" or not?

By default, XBAPs are sandboxed...

[Here](http://scorbs.com/2007/01/10/xbap-trust-levels/) is a article on how to make your XBAP full trust

More information

- [Windows Presentation Foundation Security Sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480229.aspx)

Comment: The application is in full trust mode, which is what I don't understand about it.